# Odoo: hallar el comando scaffold en Windows

Tags: windows, odoo, odoo16

Dónde puedo hallar el comando scaffold en windows 11? Según esta pregunta en inglés https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49933312/how-to-use-scaffold-to-create-module-in-windows se debería de hallar en

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 16.0.20230705\server\odoo-bin
```

pero dicha carpeta no existe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras buscarle un poco encontré el comando en la carpeta

```
C:\Program Files\Odoo 16.0.20230705\server\odoo\cli
```

Por lo que mi comando para crear un nuevo módulo quedaría como

> "C:\Program Files\Odoo 16.0.20230705\python\python.exe" "C:\Program Files\Odoo 16.0.20230705\server\odoo\cli" scaffold mi_modulo "C:\Program Files\Odoo 16.0.20230705\server\odoo\addons"

donde `mi_modulo` es el nombre del módulo a crear